# Scenarios of using RMIClassLoader and URLClassLoader?

Tags: java, class, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders, remote-execution

Could anyone explain the general purpose of these two loaders?

And what are the major differences between them?

In what typical scenarios are they used?

Answer (score 0):

URLClassLoader is for when you want to load classes from resources identifies by a URL.

RMIClassLoader is for use internally by RMI.

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you don't understand. Do you know what a class loader is? A resource? A URL?